# Agrupar y obtener mayor revision

Tags: postgresql, sql

Realmente realizar en `group by` en postgres ha sido un problema.

Estoy intentando hacer una agrupación mediante códigos y sus revisiones pero quiero obtener la ultima revisión de este código.

Aquí una estructura de la base de datos.

```
id | c_codigo |date       |created_by|precio |revision|
--------------|-----------|----------|-------|--------|
1  | MG-001   |2020-02-02 | 55       | 22222 | 1      |
2  | MG-001   |2020-02-03 | 44       | 33333 | 2      |
3  | MG-002   |2020-02-02 | 55       | 11111 | 1      |
4  | MG-003   |2020-02-02 | 44       | 55555 | 1      |
5  | MG-003   |2020-02-05 | 55       | 33333 | 2      |
```

Aqui lo que gustaría obtener

```
id | c_codigo |date       |created_by|precio |revision|
--------------|-----------|----------|-------|--------|
2  | MG-001   |2020-02-03 | 44       | 33333 | 2      |
3  | MG-002   |2020-02-02 | 55       | 11111 | 1      |
5  | MG-003   |2020-02-05 | 55       | 33333 | 2      |
```

He intentando la siguiente query. Pero no tengo los resultados esperados, ya que si agrego una columna para visualizar me pide agrupar por ese campo también.

```
SELECT  
MAX(revision),c_codigo, id 
FROM squema.main_table 
GROUP BY c_codigo,id
```

Espero haberme explicado bien. Aqui un sql Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8fc49/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL implementa la extensión `DISTINCT ON ()` de SQL que es de gran ayuda para tu caso. Puesdes hacer:

```
select distinct on (c_codigo) *
from main_table
order by c_codigo, c_revision desc
```

Resultado:

```
id  c_codigo  date        created_by  precio  c_revision 
--- --------- ----------- ----------- ------- ---------- 
2   MG-001    2020-02-03  44          33333   2          
3   MG-002    2020-02-02  55          11111   1          
5   MG-003    2020-02-05  55          33333   2
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo funcionando en [db<>fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8fc49/28).

Answer (score 0):

la cuestión es que para todas las columnas debes tener un criterio de elección, en tu query por ejemplo agrupas por id y c_codigo y quieres el máximo de la revision, si quieres que te muestre algo de date, tienes que decirle como lo elija (MAX, MIN...), lo mismo para la columna created_by y el precio, de otra manera el motor de la db no puede saber que valor mostrar.

```
    SELECT  
    id, c_codigo, MAX(date),MAX(created_by),MAX(precio),MAX(revision)
    FROM squema.main_table 
    GROUP BY c_codigo,id
```